# How to disable linting in code editor for error "type annotation" visual studio code python

Tags: python-3.x, windows, visual-studio-code

what in the problem.

[code editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KCds.png)

how i can fix it? I'm trying:

1)disable liting

2)turn all reports to "none" in python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides

[settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4iZ8.png)

I don't understand what else can I do to make this error go away ;-;

Comment: Please post the code or error as text in question, not an image.

Comment: you have `type-hinted` to a tuple...  this is an error,  so the linter is working well...

Comment: to make the error go away, you need to **fix the code** and not disable the linting.

Comment: @D.L How can I fix this error? In the annotation, I need to have several possible types

Comment: Looks like I'll have to use a decorator just to make sure the ide highlights the syntax and doesn't give a problem that wasn't there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `typing` module to achieve this:

```py
from typing import Tuple

def test(x, y: Tuple(tuple, list)):
    # do some things
    return
```

or without the module like this:

```py
def test(x, y: tuple(tuple, list)):
    # do some things
    return
```